# Use BASS.NET create MIDI Event no sound

Tags: midi

I tried to use a MIDI Event BASS.NET create and play, but it does not play properly (no sound), want to help, thank you guys! [Translation from Google]

```
public void build_MIDI() {
        BASS_MIDI_EVENT[] events ={
         new BASS_MIDI_EVENT(BASSMIDIEvent.MIDI_EVENT_TEMPO, 500000, 0, 0,0),
         new BASS_MIDI_EVENT(BASSMIDIEvent.MIDI_EVENT_PROGRAM, 1, 0, 0,0),
         new BASS_MIDI_EVENT(BASSMIDIEvent.MIDI_EVENT_NOTE, 60, 100, 0,0), 
         new BASS_MIDI_EVENT(BASSMIDIEvent.MIDI_EVENT_END, 0, 0, 0,0),
        };

        int build_play_midi_steam = BassMidi.BASS_MIDI_StreamCreateEvents(events,96, BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP, 0);
        Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(build_play_midi_steam, false);
    }
```

Comment: I do not know what language this is in; could be Java, C# or anything; but at least I know that this is no C.

Comment: It's 'midi', see the tag ;)

Comment: The initialization is missing; please prove a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you, I have solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem, the code demonstrates two notes played in steamEvent in. If you want to obtain more information about the API recommended reading

```
public void build_MIDI()
    {
        BASS_MIDI_EVENT[] events ={
         new BASS_MIDI_EVENT(BASSMIDIEvent.MIDI_EVENT_TEMPO, 500000, 0, 0,0),
         new BASS_MIDI_EVENT(BASSMIDIEvent.MIDI_EVENT_PROGRAM, 0, 0, 0,0),

         new BASS_MIDI_EVENT(BASSMIDIEvent.MIDI_EVENT_NOTE, MAKEWORD(91,100), 0, 0 ,0),
            new BASS_MIDI_EVENT(BASSMIDIEvent.MIDI_EVENT_NOTE, MAKEWORD(60,100), 0, 0 ,0),
            new BASS_MIDI_EVENT(BASSMIDIEvent.MIDI_EVENT_NOTE, 91, 0, 48,0 ),
            new BASS_MIDI_EVENT(BASSMIDIEvent.MIDI_EVENT_NOTE, 60, 0, 96,0 ),
         new BASS_MIDI_EVENT(BASSMIDIEvent.MIDI_EVENT_END, 0, 0, 2000,0),
        };

        int build_play_midi_steam = BassMidi.BASS_MIDI_StreamCreateEvents(events,100, BASSFlag.BASS_MIDI_DECAYEND | BASSFlag.BASS_MIDI_DECAYSEEK | BASSFlag.BASS_MIDI_NOFX, 1);

        Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(build_play_midi_steam, false);

    }
    ushort MAKEWORD(byte a, byte b)
    {
        return (ushort)(a | (b << 8));
    }
```